# How to use Google Calendar as backend of FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm a very beginner in this area. I read the documentation about Google Calendar in the documentation of FullCalendar. I followed the instructions and, of course, it works :)
So, I'm getting my Google appointments within FullCalendar. But I don't see anything about saving new ones, created in FullCalendar, within Google. What should I do, is it explained somewhere ?
Tx,
Louis Antoine

Comment: The integration supported by fullCalendar is read-only, since it relies on making the calendar public, and you probably don't want to make it publicly _editable_ really! So no you'd have to do something yourself combining fullCalendar and the Google Calendar API (it might make sense to do the Calendar API interaction via a server-side language, so that you can use a Service Account and always update the same account without requiring user login).

Comment: Ok. So, I understand that there is nothing off-the-shelf in FullCalendar and that I should maybe use the Zend framework I already put in place : for the time being, I have a  backend MySQL on an Apache server for my client FullCalendar written in JS and calling server functions written in PHP thru Ajax requests. The solution should then be a new service on my server using the Google Calendar API with a Service Account. Right ? Many thanks.

Comment: Well I guess you could replace the calls to mySQL with calls to the Calendar API? I am assuming you mention this because currently you store your events in mySQL but you want to store them in Google Calendar instead? Or is this some additional functionality?

Comment: Yes, it's an additional functionality of a software for physiotherapists, with FullCalendar as built-in agenda. For those ones who use already a Google agenda and want keep it synchronised. Of course the MySQL database contains lots of other data. Anyway, thank you, I will follow your advice.

Comment: By the way I wish you a happy new year ;-)

Comment: You too. If it's additional then yes alongside your calls to MySQL you can make a call to google to add the events there as well.